# TTCN-3 to XML Parser

Tags: java, xml, parsing, ttcn

**What I need: help about TTCN-3 environment**

I am actually working on the ISO 115118-4 standard which is about 
Vehicle-to-Grid Communication Interface: Network and application protocol conformance tests.

The tests cases are written in TTCN-3 and the grapical user interface is in JAVA BEANS. For now, the test cases are written in XML and I use an encoder/decoder class to convert them into Java Beans.

**I would like to know two things**:

-What are the different softwares where I could build the test cases in TTCN-3 ? I have looked on the internet but I don't find a lot of things about it.

-To convert the test cases in TTCN-3 to XML, do I need to create a convert class which will read line by line the TTCN-3 file and then build the XML file ?

Comment: What have you tried? What worked, what did not work? Looking for tools is off-topic here and better suited for [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Titan Eclipse for some years now, and I think it would be able to help you.
Links:

https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.titan

https://polarsys.org/wiki/images/9/95/TITAN_Datasheet_3.b-090914.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's still relevant, but I have used TTWorkbench for these kind of actions. You will need the XSD plugin.

Method used is to retreive the XML files as a byte array (octetstring), decode it (oct2bit) and as last use decvalue to create and fill the TTCN type based on the XSD.